# Jogo do BINGO em C , Usando matriz com 3 dimensões?

Tags: c, matriz, array-multidimensional

Como posso gerar algumas (detalhe: no plural)  cartelas aleatórias com números, mas preciso manipulá-los como uma matriz tridimensional. Cartela[jogadores] [n] [n] .. n = A dimensão

Meu programa gera apenas uma cartela, como posso gerar mais cartelas ? O índice das cartelas será definido na variável jogadores, que é a primeira dimensão da Matriz ..

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int n, soma;
int jogadores;
int menu;
int main () 
{
srand(123);

printf("Número de jogadores: \n");
do
{
scanf("%d",&jogadores);

} while (jogadores < 2 || jogadores > 10);


printf("Numero de jogadores salvo \n Escolha a dimensao das cartelas: \n");
do
{
scanf("%d",&n);

} while (n < 2 || n > 9);

printf("\n Dimensao das cartelas salva \n ");

//printf(" %d %d \n ",jogadores,n);

int value = 10*n;

 int cartela[n][n]; // I need to add the dimensiona _jogadores_ ==> cartela [jogadores][n][n]

//for (int q = 0; q <=jogadores;q++) // Loop number of players  
//{
  for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) // Loop lines of the card
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) // Loop rows of the card
    {
      do
        {
           soma = 0;
           cartela[i][j] = rand()%value; // Colocar a dimensão jogadores

       
           for (int l = 0; l < n; l++)
            {
              for (int c = 0; c < n; c++)
              {
                if(cartela[i][j] == cartela[l][c] && (i!= l && j!= c))
                {
                    soma++;
                }
              }
            
            }
        
        } while (soma != 0);  
        
     }
  }


  // for (int  j = 0; j < jogadores; j++)
  //{
    for (int l = 0;l<n;l++)
      {
    for(int c=0;c<n;c++)
    {
      printf("\t %d",cartela[l][c]);
     }
       printf("\n");
     }
  //} 




 //while(1)
//{




//}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi no lugar de `int cartela[n][n];` utilize `int cartela[jogadores][n][n];` e em cada referência à `cartela` utilize 3 índices, sendo o primeiro o referente a jogador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há outra maneira senão alocar o espaço dinamicamente para as `n` cartelas que você pode ter.
Como o número de jogadores e a dimensão da cartela são variáveis, você irá alocar esse espaço utilizando `malloc` e então poderá manipular da forma como achar mais conveniente estruturalmente falando.

Exemplo:

```
void * Data;
int DataSize;

DataSize = jogadores * (n^2) * sizeof(int);
Data = malloc(DataSize);
```

Agora você tem alocado o tamanho da matriz tridimensional que precisa, e pode acessá-la com:

```
Data[jogador][i][j]
```